# Integrating function over half-ball

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Let $B:=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2+z^2\le 4, z\ge 0\}$. Calculate $\int_B \dfrac{(x^2+y^2)z}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2}d\lambda_3(x,y,z)$.

I see that the boundary of $B$ is $D:=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:(x^2+y^2\le4,z=0)$ or $x^2+y^2+z^2=4\}$. I feel like I need to find a parametrization of $B$ and then transform it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use [spherical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) and corresponding [Jacobian determinant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In spherical coordinates, you have $$\int_B\frac{(r^2-r^2\cos^2\varphi)r\cos\varphi}{r^4}\,r\sin\varphi\, dr\, d\theta\, d\varphi$$

with $r$ fromt $0$ to $2$, $\theta$ from $0$ to $2\pi$, and $\varphi$ from $0$ to $\pi/2$. Can you simplify and take it from here?

With $r$ and $\theta$ disappearing from the calculation, you have $$4\pi\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^3(\varphi)\cos(\varphi)\,d\varphi$$ Note that symmetry makes this equal to $$4\pi\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(\varphi)\cos^3(\varphi)\,d\varphi$$ and that summing these equals (with the Pythagorean identity):$$4\pi\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(\varphi)\cos(\varphi)\,d\varphi$$ So $$2I=4\pi\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(\varphi)\cos(\varphi)\,d\varphi=4\pi\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac12\sin(2\varphi)\,d\varphi$$

(My scratch work earlier had left out that $2$ on the left.) The last integral is one lump of a sine wave, contracted both horizontally and vertically by factors $2$. Since one regular sine lump has area $2$, the last integral is $\frac12$, and therefore $I=\pi$.

Comment: How do you arrive at that, using $x=rsin\theta cos\phi,y=rsin\theta sin\phi,z=rcos\phi$ I get $(sin\theta)^3cos\theta r$ as the integrand.

Comment: I agree with @blst. The result seems correct though, the final answer is $4 \pi$.

Comment: I get 0: the first integral is $8sin\theta^3cos\theta$, and the integral of that is 0? Wolframalpha agrees.

Comment: It's not, I think you are confusing the limits. The angle in the plane $xy$ (which I used $\theta$ in my notes) takes values in the interval $[0, 2\pi]$. The angle with the $z$ axis (which I used $\varphi$ in my notes) takes values in the interval $[0, \pi/2]$. So the integral you refer to takes values in the second interval and is not zero.

Comment: We have $\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^4 r(sin\theta)^3cos\theta\, dr\, d\theta\, d\varphi$, don't we?

Comment: @blst $r^2=x^2+y^2+z^2$, which is where my denominator comes from. The quantity in the numerator $x^2+y^2=r^2-z^2$, and I am using $z=r\cos\varphi$. So that is where my integrand comes from.

Comment: @Fantini Ah I think I see what you guys are saying...how did I convert it to $\frac12\sin(2\varphi)$, is that right? Because I can't see what the problem would be with the first version. It's just trig identities.

Comment: There is no $r$ in the integrand after cancellation.

Comment: No, you guys are right - it's not the same as $\frac12\sin(2\varphi)$. My mistake - I'll edit.

Comment: I still think there is an error, it should be $0<=r<=2$, so the integral should be $\pi$.

Comment: @blst Yep - fixed.